# pass dropdown list value to controler in Asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Here am declaring a Dropdownlist in view

```
<div class="input-group">
<label class="sectionHeaderStyle" for="UserName">Select Domain</label>                   
@Html.DropDownList("DomainName", (SelectList)ViewBag.applicationList,"Select", new        {@onchange = "javascript:sendParam();" })                                         
</div>
```

here am calling javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendParam()
{
window.location = "GetGroupsListPost?id=" + jQuery("#DomainName").val();
}
</script>
```

Here is my actionresult to generate view

```
public ActionResult ManageGroups()
{
List<string> lsForest = new List<string>();
using (var forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest())
{
foreach (Domain d in forest.Domains)
{
lsForest.Add(d.Name);
}
}
var DomainList = from c in lsForest select c;
ViewData["DomainName"] = new SelectList(DomainList);
return View();
}
```

i want to read the selected value in another actionresult i.e

```
public ActionResult GetGroupsList(string strdomain)
{           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your controller Action is

```
public ActionResult GetGroupsList(string strdomain)
{           
}
```

Use, You need to pass `strdomain` as query string parameter instead of `id`

```
function sendParam()
{
   window.location.href = "GetGroupsListPost?strdomain=" + jQuery("#DomainName").val();
}
```